# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure ASP.NET Core gRPC

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, grpc

There was a problem with **gRPC** and **Docker**.
I have 3 **ASP.NET Core** projects, and one of them communicates with others via **gRPC**, when I started these projects manually, without a docker, everything worked. But in docker the problems with certificates start:

```
fail: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[6]

      Error starting gRPC call.

      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Grpc.Shared.TelemetryHeaderHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)

info: Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall[3]

      Call failed with gRPC error status. Status code: 'Internal', Message: 'Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors'.

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]

      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

      Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors

         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Grpc.Shared.TelemetryHeaderHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")

         at Votinger.Gateway.Web.Controllers.TestController.Get(String data) in /src/Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web/Controllers/TestController.cs:line 28

         at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  votinger.authserver.db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: Votinger.AuthServer.Db
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"

  votinger.pollserver.db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: Votinger.PollServer.Db
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"

  votinger.authserver.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}votingerauthserverweb
    container_name: Votinger.AuthServer.Web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Votinger.AuthServer/Votinger.AuthServer.Web/Dockerfile
    links:
        - votinger.authserver.db:authdb

  votinger.gateway.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}votingergatewayweb
    container_name: Votinger.Gateway.Web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web/Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 5000:5000
    links:
        - votinger.authserver.web:authserver
        - votinger.pollserver.web:pollserver

  votinger.pollserver.web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}votingerpollserverweb
    container_name: Votinger.PollServer.Web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Web/Dockerfile
    links:
        - votinger.pollserver.db:polldb
```

docker.compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  votinger.authserver.web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5000;http://+:5001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/https:ro

  votinger.gateway.web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5000;http://+:5001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/https:ro
  votinger.pollserver.web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5000;http://+:5001
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/https:ro
```

client Dockerfile(auto-generated by visual studio)

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web/Votinger.Gateway.Web.csproj", "Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web/Votinger.Gateway.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Votinger.Gateway/Votinger.Gateway.Web"
RUN dotnet build "Votinger.Gateway.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Votinger.Gateway.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Votinger.Gateway.Web.dll"]
```

server Dockerfile(auto-generated by visual studio)

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Web/Votinger.PollServer.Web.csproj", "Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Web/"]
COPY ["Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Infrastructure/Votinger.PollServer.Infrastructure.csproj", "Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Core/Votinger.PollServer.Core.csproj", "Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Core/"]
COPY ["Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Services/Votinger.PollServer.Services.csproj", "Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Services/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Web/Votinger.PollServer.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Votinger.PollServer/Votinger.PollServer.Web"
RUN dotnet build "Votinger.PollServer.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Votinger.PollServer.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Votinger.PollServer.Web.dll"]
```

I also found this instruction from Microsoft, I tried to follow it and nothing helped, I have already tried several options

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

Any hints would be helpful, thanks

Comment: Please paste content directly in to your question rather than reference it with hyperlinks. Please include the Dockerfile(s) that you're using to build the container images. I suspect that the images don't include the certs that you need; this can be a problem particularly if you're not installing an OS into the image.

Comment: @DazWilkin I added dockerfile and did what you asked

Comment: Thanks for that. Have a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback=HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
```